# How do I combine this media query with a specific id

Tags: css, wordpress, iframe, media-queries

I'm trying to display a 100% width iframe on my WordPress site with an existing media query and I'm trying to figure out if I can target the iframe id to be unaffected by the original media query or combine it with a unique media query to get the full frame effect with the iframe only.

This is the original code

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .responsive #top #wrap_all .container {
        width: 85%;
        max-width: 85%;
    }
}
```

and this is how I need it to function, but only with id tag `#frame`

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .responsive #top #wrap_all .container {
        width: 100%!important;
        max-width: 100%!important;
    }
}
```

I feel like this is a few seconds from complete, but I'm not sure how to finish it.

Comment: If you only need it to work with `#frame` then why not just use `#frame` in your query?

Comment: I did a bad job initially explaining my problem. I was altering existing code, but I need it to affect only #frame instead of the whole site.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions is not very clear. Then if your unique iframe ID is `#frame`, you can target it:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    /* your iframe */
    .responsive #frame { 
        width: 100%!important;
        max-width: 100%!important;
    }
}
```

You can add more rules and you can target other selectors inside this media query too…

Comment: They didn't edit the code, no. They altered whitespace, nothing more. It was the OP that added the missing brace.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `}` at the end, as well as you can tag multiple elements onto CSS declarations, so you could do this if you wanted the `#frame` element to have the same properties, so your current code looks like this:-

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .responsive #top #wrap_all .container {
    width: 100%!important;
    max-width: 100%!important;
  }
} // <-- Notice the ending bracket that you missed off, I added that.
```

Then you could tag on another element with a `,` like so:-

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .responsive #top #wrap_all .container, #iframe { // <-- see the , and the element?
    width: 100%!important;
    max-width: 100%!important;
  }
} // <-- Notice the ending bracket that you missed off, I added that.
```

I know this is long winded, but I tried to go in depth rather than just giving you the example so you fully understood, hope I helped :)

Comment: See my comment on the other answer (OP just forgot to add the last closing bracket to the question); this answer is no longer applicable.